# Contact->Account - Insufficient access on Contact when Account is null?

Tags: apex

For a custom profile, I am unable to access a Contact with 'Systemadmin' as the owner. It throws INSUFFICIENT access. I checked the profile settings on Contact and it has CRUD access and the sharing settings are PublicRead/write.

However, when I populated the Contact with an Account as a SystemAdmin, then this Contact record is accessible to the custom profile.

why did the access change when I just populated the Contact with Account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contacts without Accounts are Private Contacts. Private Contacts are only visible to the Owner and System Administrators, regardless of Sharing Model. [Help & Training](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contacts_private.htm&type=5) has this to say:

> Contacts that aren’t associated with an account are always private, regardless of your organization’s sharing model. Before allowing private contacts, consider the downside: they're easy to forget because they're hidden from all users except their owner and the system administrator.

This allows users to have non-business contacts in their Salesforce without cluttering other peoples' views and reports. This is a standard feature that cannot be disabled. If you need a contact to be visible to more than just the Owner and System Administrators, it must have an Account.

Note that the Account relationship on Contacts is a hybrid between a Master-Detail and a Lookup (even though it shows as a Lookup); deleting an Account also deletes its Contact records, as if it were a Master-Detail, and Accounts can grant access to Contacts that are under it, just like a Master-Detail, but Contacts can also be shared individually, like a Lookup, and can have a different owner than the Account, just like a Lookup. Standard relationships are almost always a "Special Hybrid" type of relationship; even though the UI says that it is a Lookup, it's got more power than a custom lookup relationship does.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox, Thanks for the detailed explanation. It is an eye-opener.